# How to create non-Modal (Non-UI-Blocking) PopUpScreen in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, popup, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am working on adding a simple popUpScreen with a texual information when you hover over a CustomButton in BlackBerry. I have seen this already implemented in applications like Twitter, Facebbok and even in native BlackBerry pictures app and many other places.

To clarify, What i need is something like this -

[a busy cat http://bit.ly/rh5gy7](http://bit.ly/rh5gy7) 
[popupscreen as shown with a red circle]

But, I have not been able to create a PopUpScreen that is non-modal and non-ui-blocking. 
That is, even when the popupscreen is being shown, I should be able to move focus on the screen that called the popUpScreen.

Can anyone tell me, perhaps with some code, as to how you can implement this!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The picture looks more like a toolbar, is this what you're after? http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Toolbar_1247236_11.jsp

Comment: Hi Ray, Yes, the one in the picture is a toolbar. But I am more interested in getting that popUpScreen that reads "Show Search". Any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: Aha, I get ya. That's a tooltip and in this case it's part of the toolbar class. On that link I gave you scroll down to where it says StringProvider("butn1") "butn1" is the text used in the tooltip

Comment: Hey Ray, that was really helpful. I haven't been looking at the 6.0 API reference as I usually target OS 4.5 and above. Have missed this completely. Thanks a lot. And also, if someone wants to implement this tooltip for OS below 6.0 ..here's a nice tutorial with sample code. http://www.naviina.eu/wp/blackberry/390/

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, even if you put it together yourself, you should post it as an answer and accept it so others will know this question has been resolved.

Comment: @ChethanRao You're welcome. In case you are interested the videos RIM put up are quite handy for quickly catching up on the UI stuff. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-6-User-Interface-APIs/ta-p/557303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above can be achieved by making use of [ToolBarManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/toolbar/ToolbarManager.html) and adding [ToolbarButtonField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/toolbar/ToolbarButtonField.html) into it and then setting a string as [tooltip](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/toolbar/ToolbarButtonField.html#setTooltip(net.rim.device.api.util.StringProvider)) which will act as a popupscreen as shown in the above picture. ToolBarManager is available only in OS 6.0 and abob

If you intend to use this feature in older OS versions of BlackBerry, [here's](http://www.naviina.eu/wp/blackberry/390/) is a nice tutorial with sample resource.

Thank you [Ray Vahey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198624/ray-vahey) for your help!